# Isn't there a Voltage drop across a resistor?

Tags: load

I've been reading this [Wikipedia - Electrical Load](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_load) topic and there is a section which is confusing me... So what you do is go to the ***"A more technical approach"*** section in this topic and then read the 4th line which starts with *"With no load (open-circuited terminals)..."*.

[image]

Now the line says that *"With no load (open-circuited terminals), all of Vs falls across the output; the output voltage is Vs."* But how? Isn't there be a voltage drop across the resistor Rs? If not, why not?

Answer (score 6):

No, the page is corrrect. The voltage drop across the resistor is equal to the current through the resistor multiplied by the resistance.

V=IR

The current is zero, therefore the voltage drop is zero, and Vs is present at the output.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't there be a voltage drop across the resistor Rs?? If not, why
>   not??

No, there is zero volts *across* a resistor, by Ohm's Law, when there is zero current *through* the resistor.

If the load is an open circuit, there is zero current through \$R_S\$ and so, the voltage across \$R_S\$ is \$0V\$.

By KVL:

$$V_S = V_{Rs} + V_{OUT} = 0V + V_{OUT}$$

and so,

$$V_S = V_{OUT}$$